TFLite model does not detect objects properly in Flutter
Can someone help me with the custom TF Lite model and Flutter using google_mlkit_object_detection: 0.13.0
Currently, I use the code below to try getting the detected objects and assign labels to them:
 Future<void> labelImage(File imageFile) async {
    final modelPath = await getModelPath('assets/ml/model.tflite');
    final InputImage inputImage = InputImage.fromFile(imageFile);
    const mode = DetectionMode.single;

    final options = LocalObjectDetectorOptions(
      mode: mode,
      modelPath: modelPath,
      classifyObjects: true,
      multipleObjects: true,
      maximumLabelsPerObject: 39,
    );

    final objectDetector = ObjectDetector(options: options);

    final List<DetectedObject> objects =
        await objectDetector.processImage(inputImage);
}


In IOS, I can only see one object with an actual label Shorts while the rest of the objects have label with "Entitiy" as the text.
In Android, all the detected objects have the empty list of labels.

Here's the codes I made following the Google CodeLab with Model Maker
import tensorflow as tf
assert tf.__version__.startswith('2')

from tflite_model_maker import image_classifier
from tflite_model_maker.image_classifier import DataLoader
from tflite_model_maker.config import ExportFormat
from tflite_model_maker import model_spec

data_dir="D:\\images_group_selected"

BATCH_SIZE = 4
EPOCHS = 8

data = DataLoader.from_folder(data_dir)

train_data, rest_data = data.split(0.8)
validation_data, test_data = rest_data.split(0.5)

model = image_classifier.create(
  train_data, 
  validation_data=validation_data, 
  epochs=EPOCHS, 
  train_whole_model=True, 
  batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
  model_spec=model_spec.get('mobilenet_v2'),
  shuffle=True)

model.summary()

model.export(export_dir='.', export_format=ExportFormat.TFLITE)
model.export(export_dir='.', export_format=ExportFormat.LABEL)

model.evaluate_tflite('model.tflite', test_data)

In my data structure, each directory would contain all the data belongs to a class (a label)
class1
-- image_class1_1.jpg
-- image_class1_2.jpg
class2
-- image_class2_1.jpg
-- image_class2_2.jpg
...

I suspect that since I created an image classifier, it does not work well with the ObjectDetector in Flutter. I really appreciate any advice about this issue.
